# Trying to combine a list into sublists for players in a blackjack game using python

Tags: python, list, recursion, append, blackjack

I'm working on making my own blackjack game without using other solutions. This is just part of the code because I'm working in steps. I want to combine a list of cards in order to make a new list for each player. I have for the first pair cards dealt to 4 players:

```
shuffled_deck = [['A', '♦'], ['6', '♣'], ['2', '♥'], ['Q', '♦'], ['K', '♦'], ['3', '♠'], ['8', '♠'], ['9', '♠']]

players = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

desired output>>

```
[[['A', '♦'], ['K', '♦']], [['6', '♣'], ['3', '♠']], [['2', '♥'], ['8', '♠']], [['Q', '♦'], ['9', '♠']]]
```

Its's just dealing two cards to 4 players, like in blackjack.
I can create it using this:

```
#EXAMPLE 1    
for i in range(0,4):
    players[i] = [shuffled_deck[i]]

for j in range(0,4):
    players[j].append(shuffled_deck[j+4])
```

But I'd like to do it with something like this, but can't figure out how.

```
count = 0
people = []

def combine_2_cards(people=[], count=count):
    while count < 8:
        people.append(shuffled_deck.pop(0))
        count += 1 
        return combine_2_cards(people, count)
    return people

players = combine_2_cards(people, count)
```

Which just creates the original shuffled_cards list. Maybe there's even a better way?

I need to make it append like in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

How this works: 
first the base case of the recursion is when cards is empty, instead 
of the classic "if (basecase) else (do stuff)" we're checking if the cards list is not empty, we fill players

how players are filled: pop 2 cards from `cards` list, when i is 0, pop the first element, when i is 1, pop the middle card, then add both to cards list as a list

do this again and again till we reach the base case.

```
def combine_2_cards(players, cards):
    if cards: 
        # assign 2 cards to 1 players 
        current_cards = [card for card in [cards.pop(0 if i % 2 == 0 else len(cards) // 2) for i in range(2)]]
        players.append(current_cards)
        combine_2_cards(players, cards)
    return players

print(combine_2_cards([], shuffled_deck))
# prints: [[['A', '♦'], ['K', '♦']], [['6', '♣'], ['3', '♠']], [['2', '♥'], ['8', '♠']], [['Q', '♦'], ['9', '♠']]]
```

Comment: if I already have a skeleton set of players already set, like 
`players = [[], [], [], []]`

Comment: If I try to pass that to the function the results aren't correct. Whats the best way to halt the function once it reaches the player limit?

Comment: Also, how can the function choose the first n*2 cards from the shuffled deck where n is the number of players?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice(i, None, x)` to get every `x`th element, starting from the `i`th element.

For example,

```
[shuffled_deck[slice(i, None, 4)] for i in range(4)]
```

will deal the shuffled deck to 4 players, as per your desired output. The second argument of `slice` can be used to control how much of the deck you want to deal (here `None` to shuffle the whole deck).

Here is a more general function.

```
def deal(deck, n_players, n_cards=None):
    """Deals a deck to players.

    Args:
        n_players (int): Number of players.
        n_cards (int): Number of cards from the deck to deal.

    Returns:
        A list containing the hands for each player.

    """
    return [deck[slice(i, n_cards, n_players)] for i in range(n_players)]
```

If you have list which contains the number of players, you can use

```
players = deal(shuffled_deck, len(players))
```

to deal them a new hand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much @pidgeyUsedGust and @Fibi. While I haven't worked with comprehensions yet, I think I can better get the gist of them now. 
I also ran my function twice and created the desired output like so,

```
players = [[], [], [], []]
count = 0
people = []

def combine_2_cards(people=[], count=count): 
    while count < 4:
        players[count].append(shuffled_deck.pop(0))
        count += 1
        return combine_2_cards(players, count)
    return people


players = combine_2_cards(people, count)
players = combine_2_cards(people, count)
```

Comment: Just a few additional remarks. First, [don't give a list as a default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/). Second, I'd suggest not changing global variables within a method. Either supply it as an argument or create the list inside the method. Third, the `.pop()` method will edit the shuffled_deck list, which might have unintended consequences.

Comment: I think I understand your first remark. About using the `.pop()` method in this case, I need to because the shuffled_deck is like a real card deck used in blackjack.